# Yarn Installation error, View Storefront installation

Tags: vue.js, vue-storefront

While I am trying Install Vue Storefront in my windows 10 machine, it generate yarn installation issue.

Please refer the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Are you running `cmd` in Administrator mode?

Comment: Ya sure, I am running administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Vue storefront does not support direct Windows workflows.

please follow:
https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/windows.html#requirements

to install vue-storefront on Windows. Docker is the only supported method for this.

Answer (score 0):

To install Vue storefront on windows platform.
Please visit the once: 
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zL_T3WzVLG0**

Which already explains well, how to install and what needs to be installed in your window system.